# Активный пункт меню

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, php

Добрый вечер. Делаю интернет-магазин на движке OpenCart. Вывел главное меню, задал ему стилей. Но не могу сообразить как выделить активные пункты меню. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как мне быть? Заранее спасибо! ( Хотел вставить код меню, но не могу разобраться как, по этому вот ссылка на сам магазин - http://fishing-trade.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php if ($category['active']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Это работает, но мне нужно выделять пункт меню, а не категорию. Я о (главная,закладки и т.д.). Не подскажите как с этим меню быть? Вот код -   
<ul>
<li><a class="maina" href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
  </ul>

Answer (score 0):

Можно например использовать js при загрузки страниц смотреть url и после этого добавлять в нужный тег class active